# MySQL OUTER Join with AS

Tags: mysql

I have quite the beast of a SQL statement and I was hoping for a little help. I have found that I need to be using an OUTER join for some of these tables but MySQL doesn't have that function.

```
            SELECT validclick.CampaignName AS CampaignName, 
                validclick.Website AS Website, 
                validclick.RevClicks AS RevClicks, 
                validclick.Revenue AS Revenue, 
                validclick.TQ AS TQ,
                validclick.Source AS Source, 
                validclick.ScoredClicks AS ScoredClicks, 
                validclick.Searches AS Searches, 
                vci.Impressions AS Impressions, 
                (validclick.RevClicks / validclick.Searches * 100) AS CTR, 
                (IFNULL(yaho.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(google.Spend, 0)) AS Spend, 
                (IFNULL(yaho.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(google.PaidClicks, 0)) AS PaidClicks, 
                (validclick.Revenue -  
                    (IFNULL(yaho.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(google.Spend, 0))) AS Profit, 
                (validclick.TQ / validclick.ScoredClicks) AS ScoredTQ,  
                (validclick.TQ / validclick.RevClicks) AS UnscoredTQ, 
                (validclick.Revenue /  
                    (IFNULL(yaho.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(google.PaidClicks, 0))) AS RPI, 
                (validclick.Revenue / validclick.RevClicks) AS RPC,  
                ((IFNULL(yaho.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(google.Spend, 0)) / 
                    (IFNULL(yaho.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(google.PaidClicks, 0))) AS CPC, 
                ((validclick.Revenue -  
                    (IFNULL(yaho.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(google.Spend, 0))) / 
                    (IFNULL(yaho.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.Spend, 0) + IFNULL(google.Spend, 0)) * 100) AS ROI, 
                (validclick.RevClicks /  
                    (IFNULL(yaho.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(facebook.PaidClicks, 0) + IFNULL(google.PaidClicks, 0)) * 100) AS Conversion 
            FROM 
                (SELECT camp.CampaignName AS CampaignName, 
                    MAX(camp.Website) AS Website, 
                    MAX(camp.Source) AS Source, 
                    SUM(vc.Clicks) AS RevClicks, 
                    SUM(vc.Revenue) AS Revenue, 
                    SUM(vc.TQ) AS TQ, 
                    SUM(vc.ScoredClicks) AS ScoredClicks, 
                    SUM(vc.BiddedSearches) AS Searches 
                FROM 
                    (SELECT AffID, 
                        MAX(CampaignName) AS CampaignName, 
                        Website, 
                        MAX(Source) AS Source 
                    FROM campaigns 

                    GROUP BY AffID) AS camp 
                JOIN 
                    (SELECT AffID, 
                        SUM(Clicks) AS Clicks, 
                        SUM(AffiliateRevenue) AS Revenue, 
                        SUM(BiddedSearches) AS BiddedSearches, 
                        SUM(CASE WHEN TQ > 0 THEN (TQ * Clicks) ELSE NULL END) AS TQ, 
                        SUM(CASE WHEN TQ > 0 THEN Clicks ELSE NULL END) AS ScoredClicks 
                    FROM validclickvc 
                    WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-05-06' AND '2018-05-07' 
                    GROUP BY AffID) AS vc 
                ON vc.AffID = camp.AffID 
                GROUP BY camp.CampaignName) AS validclick 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT CampaignName, 
                    SUM(Spend) AS Spend,
                    SUM(OutboundClicks) AS PaidClicks 
                FROM facebookads 
                WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-05-06' AND '2018-05-07' 
                GROUP BY CampaignName) AS facebook 
            ON validclick.CampaignName = facebook.CampaignName 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT CampaignName, 
                    SUM(Spend) AS Spend,
                    SUM(Clicks) AS PaidClicks 
                FROM yahoo 
                WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-05-06' AND '2018-05-07' 
                GROUP BY CampaignName) AS yaho 
            ON validclick.CampaignName = yaho.CampaignName 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT CampaignName, 
                    SUM(Cost) AS Spend,
                    SUM(Clicks) AS PaidClicks 
                FROM adwords 
                WHERE Date BETWEEN '2018-05-06' AND '2018-05-07' 
                GROUP BY CampaignName) AS google 
            ON validclick.CampaignName = google.CampaignName 
            LEFT JOIN 
                (SELECT camp.CampaignName AS CampaignName, 
                    SUM(vc.Impressions) AS Impressions 
                FROM 
                    (SELECT AffID, 
                        MAX(CampaignName) AS CampaignName 
                    FROM campaigns 

                    GROUP BY AffID) AS camp 
                JOIN 
                    (SELECT ty AS AffID, 
                        COUNT(DISTINCT(id)) AS Impressions 
                    FROM validclickimpressions 
                    WHERE ts BETWEEN '2018-05-06 00:00' AND '2018-05-07 23:59' 
                    GROUP BY AffID) AS vc 
                ON vc.AffID = camp.AffID 
                GROUP BY camp.CampaignName) AS vci 
            ON validclick.CampaignName = vci.CampaignName 
            ORDER BY CampaignName;
```

I'm aware this may not be the most efficient MySQL statement, but we will soon be changing the structure of things so i's not a big deal. For now I need some way to use OUTER join, or do a LEFT JOIN UNTION RIGHT JOIN but with an alias. The tables (aliases) I need to full join are vci, facebook, google, and yaho. Any ideas on how to tackle this?

Comment: Left and right joins are also outer joins. Do you mean full outer join (this is the onenot supported by mysql)? Also, no idea where you want to use a full outer join, there is no sample data, nor expected output. This way it is pretty impossible to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry yes a full outer join. I will provide some data too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does not support `FULL [OUTER] JOIN`.

We can emulate a full outer join in MySQL using two separate select, combining the results. The pattern of an outer join and an anti-join.

```
 -- outer join (all rows from a along with matching rows from b) 
 SELECT ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON ...

 UNION ALL

 -- anti-join (rows from b with no matching row in a) 
 SELECT ... FROM b LEFT JOIN a ON ... WHERE a.notnull_col IS NULL
```

---

As a simplistic demonstration, two tables a and b:

```
 table a   table b
      an        bn
 -------   -------
       1         2
       2         3
       3         5
       4         7
```

Example query

```
  -- left outer join (rows in a with matching rows from b) 
  SELECT a.an, b.bn
    FROM a
    LEFT
    JOIN b
      ON b.bn = a.an

   UNION ALL

  -- anti-join (rows from b with no match in a)
  SELECT a.an, b.bn
    FROM b
    LEFT
    JOIN a 
      ON a.an = b.bn
   WHERE a.an IS NULL
```

should return something like this (without ORDER BY clause, order of rows is indeterminate)

```
      an        bn
 -------   -------
       1    (NULL)
       2         2
       3         3
       4    (NULL)
  (NULL)         5
  (NULL)         7
```